# Open XML file in NodeJS in the same folder - No such file

Tags: node.js, xml

I'm trying to open an XML file that is in the same folder of my controller.
I have the files:

controllers/test/myController.js
controllers/test/myXML.xml

The myXML.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<something>

</something>
```

myController.js file:

```
exports.getXML = async (req, res, next) => {
    const xmlFile = fs.readFileSync('./myXML.xml', 'utf8');
    console.log(xmlFile);
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './myXML.xml'
```

I tried to change './myXML.xml' to 'myXML.xml' and I also get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Paths are resolved relative to the current working directory, not the location of the module.

You can use [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) to get the path to the directory containing the module, then you can append your filename to that.